# Corebluetooth - maintain connection on iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

So sum up, I have a device communicating via ble to my application. The application uses Corebluetooth to handle the connection and communication.

The problem:

When a device goes out of range it will disconnect -> it calls the diddisconnect() function where I check if its timed out and call the central.connect again.

it will then start the connection and immediately on some devices(only iOS14) at the moment, it will go to didfailtoconnect with an error saying:

"Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=15 "Failed to encrypt the connection, the connection has timed out unexpectedly." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encrypt the connection, the connection has timed out unexpectedly."

Only seem to exist on iOS14 devices as far as I have seen.

I also tested blocking signals, if i block signals from device the issue is not apparent. if I block signals from phone, the issue is apparent. Not sure how this is, feels like they both trigger timeout.

May be problem elsewhere aswell but it seem to handle fine on my iOS13 device.(mainly tested on 4 phones, 2 on each version)

Also to clarify, the application is acting as the central, and the device as the peripheral.

Comment: You are making mistake. Once your device is out of range you should only advertise it if device is in range not connecting to device directly. connecting is producting error bcz device isnt available.

Comment: @Kudos thanks for reply, but from my understanding calling the connect would queue the connection at system level until it found the device(or bluetooth / phone was turned off). Do you have any good example of how you mean, to maintain the connection when device gets in range?

Comment: Yeah Like if you are working with honor band 5. If its out of range you will be disconnected. Then you can just start scanning for device not making connecting until its scanned.

Comment: @Kudos Yeah I should try initate a scan as the device disconnect. As far as I can see in apples documentation there is 3 approaches. two of them is get the known or connected peripherals from system and try to connect. Third is like you say, you scan with services. I just dont get why its working phones prior to iOS14.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret the error message correctly from CBErrorEncryptionTimedOut (15), it means that the devices initiated a connection, then, suddenly after the iOS device initiated the encryption procedure, the connection unexpectedly died.

So it should be treated more or less the same way as CBErrorConnectionTimeout (6).

If this happens all the time, you should use a BLE sniffer to see what's going on; maybe it's some bug in iOS.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be pretty consistent on disconnects when the device go out of range and the iPhone iOS version is 14.xx.. 
Funny thing is, I tested distrupting the signal using a microwave(not turned on) and the outcome from that is that if I put the phone in the microwave, leave it for a minute and take it out the problem exists. if I do the same but with the device in the microwave - not an issue.
Tested the approach also as you mention, to treat it as a timeout and reconnect. it loops the function a few times but it keeps the connection in the end.